# problem in use of nested git repository in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, nested, jenkins-pipeline

I create two local git repository. in the first repository, I put my Jenkinsfile. in my Jenkins file, I use the second git repository.
now the problem is when I want to fetch author name of the second repository for using some purpose, it uses from the first repository that contains Jenkinsfile.
how can I fix this issue?
I want to fetch author name of the second repository that is in the jenkinsfile.

[image]

Comment: have you tried putting another empty jenkinsfile in second git repository ??

Comment: no. 
in jenkinsfile I use git command for fetching my project.

git([url: 'xxxxxxxxxx.git', branch: "master"])

Comment: @rajenderkumar a lot of the time we don't have contribution rights to the other git repositories. So, I don't think that is a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Git repositories almost always have more than one author. Sometimes the original author has the most number of commits, and you can search for the author that way.

One way to do this is by using the [command](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4519/list-all-authors-of-a-particular-git-project):

```
git log --format='%aN <%aE>' | awk '{arr[$0]++} END{for (i in arr){print arr[i], i;}}' | sort -rn | cut -f2- | head -1
```

This command gets the authors, sorts by the number of commits, and then outputs the first result.

You can add it to your Jenkinsfile in a `sh` block.

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage("Checkout") {
      steps {
        git([url: 'xxxxxxxxxx.git', branch: "master"])
        sh 'cd xxxxxxxxx.git'
        sh 'git log --format=\'%aN <%aE>\' | awk \'{arr[$0]++} END{for (i in arr){print arr[i], i;}}\' | sort -rn | cut -f2- | head -1 >author.txt'
        sh 'cat author.txt'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: my problem isn't about how fetching author name.
when I use command for the fetch author name, instead of the second repository second, it returns first repository author name.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on when you haven't provided the Jenkinsfile.